# How can I change config of istiod deployment using istio-operator?

Tags: istio, amazon-eks, calico, kubernetes-operator, istio-operator

I am setting up istio controlplane using istio-operator on an EKS cluster with calico CNI. After installing istio on the cluster, I got to know that new pods are not coming up and the reason I got after googling is given below:

[Istio Installation successful but not able to deploy POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159786/istio-installation-successful-but-not-able-to-deploy-pod)

Now, I want to apply a change `hostNetwork: true` under `spec.template.spec` to istiod deployment using the istio-operator only.

I did some more googling to change or override the values of istiod deployment and got the following yamls files:

https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/ca541df418d0902ebeb9506c84d24c6bd9743801/operator/cmd/mesh/testdata/manifest-generate/input

But they are also not working. Below is the last configurations I have applied:

```
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: zeta-zone-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: minimal
  values:
    pilot:
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 222m
          memory: 333Mi
    hostNetwork: true
  unvalidatedValues:
    hostNetwork: true
```

Can anybody help me to add `hostNetwork: true` under `spec.template.spec` to istiod deployment using the istio-operator only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve that using the following YAML after a lot of hit and trials and checking logs of istio-operator:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: minimal
  hub: docker.io/istio
  tag: 1.10.3
  meshConfig:
    rootNamespace: istio-system
  components:
    base:
      enabled: true
    pilot:
      enabled: true
      namespace: istio-system
      k8s:
        overlays:
        - kind: Deployment
          name: istiod
          patches:
          - path: spec.template.spec.hostNetwork
            value: true # OVERRIDDEN
```